# Firefox Crashes when watching video or playing flash games

Tags: firefox, video, flash, crash, bsod

Firefox crashes on me when I'm watching videos or playing flash games.  Once in awhile, instead of just firefox crashing it'll result in a full blown blue screen with "irql_not_less_or_equal."  Any advice?

EDIT: After reinstalling flash to the latest version, I received another blue screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Flash is crashy, granted. But it's a plain userland application which should not be able to generate bluescreens.

So either you have a hardware problem, or something in the OS is messed up — quite possibly the graphics card drivers. Right-click a Flash embed (one that doesn't hide the default menu) and choose ‘Settings’, then on the ‘Display tab’ untick ‘Enable hardware acceleration’. If this stops it crashing, your graphics drivers need looking at.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not Flash. IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL indicates a hardware problem.

See [this article](http://www.tweaksforgeeks.com/IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL.html) for more information.

Comment: Yes, guess this is a hardware problem or problem with the video or audio drivers

Answer (score 0):

Watching videos and playing flash games have "Flash" in common.
I would recommend you to reinstall the Flash plugin.

You can find the [installer here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)

Comment: I don't think it relate with crash because I have installed flash but sometime crash happen for me

Comment: I reinstalled flash but while playing a flash game just now I got another BSOD.  This time There was no message similar to the IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL and simply said it was trying to prevent damage to my computer

Answer (score 0):

Try running a memory test to make sure you don't have problems with your physical RAM; in Windows Vista there is a built-in memory test which should suit your needs, but for XP/other you might need to use a memtest86 or memtest64 boot disc.  This may not be your problem, but for me Firefox was always the "Canary in a Coal Mine" that detected when I was about to have memory problems.

I have also noticed that some newer computers tend to have components (motherboards, specifically) that are very sensitive to dust, and a can of compressed air might do wonders; about every 2-3 months I open up my case, thoroughly dust everything including the DIMMs themselves and the ports into which they fit.  Sometimes, in fact, this will seem to "correct" memory problems as it eliminates electrical noise.  DO NOT ATTEMPT THIS IF YOU ARE NOT SURE WHAT YOU ARE DOING; IF YOU DO NOT KNOW HOW TO GROUND YOURSELF PROPERLY YOU CAN AND WILL KILL YOUR RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Shockwave Flash is NOT enabled in the Add Ins section of Firefox. Also, in options of Firefox, disable "Hardware Acceleration".